# Include files from function

Tags: php

I am trying to include a file from a function. This function doesn't return anything, it is just initializing many things.

This function also apply the language so I need to include the language file. But it seems like the scope isn't the same.

How can I include a file from a function as global ?

Ex :

```
function StartUp() {
    include('test.php'); // I want to make the vars in test.php available in a Global Scope.
}
```

Comment: Can't you just include the file in the global scope instead? Or better yet, have some configuration class that you can use to get the information you need, when you need it. It's good to avoid (and depend on) global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *include* external files in the function and make all the vars global in it because if you do so they remain the in scope of that function only, better way you just include them by a simple way without any function.

Or you can just add a global keyword in front of your all variables to make them global all over.

Comment: That's not entirely true. You can solve it by adding: `global $theVarName;` before the include inside the function. It's really bad practice though.

Comment: But it is not a better approach to include them in a function .

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I was answering your statement: _"You cannot include external files in the function and make all the vars global "_, which you can by adding `global $var1, $var2, ...` inside the function right before you include the file that defines them. But as mentioned, it's a terrible idea but it _can_ be done.

Comment: Yes that's true i'll change my statement

Comment: Ok, I was curious, but btw, I was able to include directly without using a function. So now that I understand, I've included my files directly. Thanx you !

Comment: Glad to help you:)